# Jquery returns undefined for reference to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value from a `JSON` variable using a `JQuery` function, but the results say undefined.

```
var $submit = $('#Submit');
$(function () {
$submit.click(function(){
     var Names = [{'1': 'Bob', '2': 'Jim'}];
     alert(Names['2']);

    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxof0220/

Comment: you maybe want a array with names? `["Bob", "Jim"]`

Comment: There's no JSON involved in this question. There is an array with an object. JSON is a string format.

Comment: The question and the given code make absolutely no sense ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Names` looks like an array with a single element. Try this:

```
var Names = [{'1': 'Bob', '2': 'Jim'}];
alert(Names[0]['2']);
```

```js
var $submit = $('#Submit');
$(function () {
     $submit.click(function(){
        var Names = [{'1': 'Bob', '2': 'Jim'}];
        alert(Names[0]['2']); 
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button id="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Data</button>
```

Comment: New it was something easy I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

remove the brackets in variable "Names"
here is the correct code:

```
var Names = {'1': 'Bob', '2': 'Jim'};
```